# Wp_User_Query timing out

Tags: wordpress

I have a multisite WordPress site that has 70K registered users and when performing a user query it times out on a server with the max execution time set to 3 mins. A query shouldn't take nowhere near that long in the first place. What could be causing this issue? See the query below.

```
$args = array (
    'role'      => 'employer',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'orderby'   => 'user_registered',
    'blog_id'   => 4,
);
```

When I use that code with blog_id = 0. The server doesn't time out and completes the query however, it returns all users regardless of role.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line before your query. It will solve your problem if any issue with execution timeout.

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is slow for many reasons. Perhaps the biggest reason is your using `WP_User_Query`, which, well, um, should not be used. *(If there was a Rube Goldberg contest for code, class-wp-user-query.php should be entered.)*

And finally, the WP `get_results()` methods should never be used when a query could return a large amount of data; they **can cause CPU and memory issues**. Use a `while()` loop and get results row-by-row.